# Transforming HTML with XQuery

Tags: html, qt, transform, xquery

I'm wanting to take the HTML generated by a QTextEdit editor and transform it to something a little more friendly for use in an actual web page.  Unfortunately, the HTML generator that is part of the QTextEdit api is not public and cannot be modified.  I'd rather not have to create a WYSIWYG html editor when I have most of what I need built in.

In a short discussion on the qt-interest mailing list, someone mentioned using XQuery via the QtXmlPatterns module.

For an example of the ugly HTML the editor outputs, it uses `<span style=" font-weight:600">` for bold text, `<span style=" font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline">` for bold and underline text, etc.  Here's a sample:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style=" font-family:'Lucida Grande'; font-size:14pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text</p>
    <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"></p>
    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text <span style=" font-weight:600;">bold text</span></p>
    <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-weight:600;"></p>
    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text <span style=" font-style:italic;">italics text</span></p>
    <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-style:italic;"></p>
    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text <span style=" text-decoration: underline;">underline text</span></p>
    <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"></p>
    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text <span style=" font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;">bold underline text</span></p>
    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text <span style=" font-weight:600;">bold text </span><span style=" font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;">bold underline text</span></p>  
  </body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to transform this into is something along the lines of this:

```
<body>
   <p>plain text</p>
   <p/>
   <p>plain text <b>bold text</b></p>
   <p/>
   <p>plain text <em>italics text</em></p>
   <p/>
   <p>plain text <u>underline text</u></p>
   <p/>
   <p>plain text <b>bold text <u>bold underline text</u></b></p>
</body>
```

I've gotten around 90% of the way to where I need to be.  I can correctly transform the first 4 where each `<span>` style member has only one of the italics, bold, or underline attributes.  I'm having trouble when the span style has multiple attributes. For instance, if the span style has both `font-weight:600` and `text-decoration: underline`.

Here's my XQuery code that I have thus far:

```
declare function local:process_span_data($node as node())
{
    for $n in $node
    return (
        for $attr in $n/@style
        return (
            if(contains($attr, 'font-weight:600')) then (
                <b>{data($n)}</b>
            )
            else if(contains($attr, 'text-decoration: underline')) then (
                <u>{data($n)}</u>
            )
            else if (contains($attr, 'font-style:italic')) then (
                <em>{data($n)}</em>
            )
            else (
                data($n)
            )
        )
    )
};

declare function local:process_p_data($data as node()+)
{
    for $d in $data
    return (
        if ($d instance of text()) then $d
        else local:process_span_data($d)
    )
};

let $doc := doc('myfile.html')

for $body in $doc/html/body
return
    <body>
    {
    for $p in $body/p
    return (
        if (contains($p/@style, '-qt-paragraph-type:empty;')) then (
            <p />
        )
        else (
            if (count($p/*) = 0) then (
                <p>{data($p)}</p>
            )
            else (
                <p>
                {for $data in $p/node()
                return local:process_p_data($data)}
                </p>
            )
        )
    )
    }</body>
```

Which gives **ALMOST** the correct result:

```
<body>
    <p>plain text</p>
    <p/>
    <p>plain text <b>bold text</b>
    </p>
    <p/>
    <p>plain text <em>italics text</em>
    </p>
    <p/>
    <p>plain text <u>underline text</u>
    </p>
    <p/>
    <p>plain text <b>bold underline text</b>
    </p>
    <p>plain text <b>bold text </b>
        <b>bold underline text</b> <!-- NOT UNDERLINED!! -->
    </p>
</body>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of achieving my desired output?  Thanks in advance from an XQuery n00b!

Comment: I have no idea what xquery is, but the problem is that the code checks once if the element has a style, and returns a value. You would have to check all values of the element and then return it.

Comment: One has to be rather masochistic to decide not to use XSLT for this. An XSLT solution is trivial and would require just two minutes to write. :)

Comment: How long would it take to write for someone who knows nothing of XSLT, though?

Comment: Is `<b>bold text </b><b><u>bold underline text</u></b>` a viable output, or would it need to be `<b>bold text <u>bold underline text</u></b>`? The former is much simpler to achieve.

Comment: @Flynn1179: That is a viable output.

Comment: @Grant Limberg: Check my answer for a map to XQuery from my previous XSLT [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903860/ambiguous-rule-match-in-replacing-style-attributes-in-xhtml-via-xslt/4906881#4906881)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your approach is correct but XQuery transformation logic is bit non-functional paradigm approach.

check out this.

```
xquery version '1.0-ml';
declare namespace mittai = "mittai";

declare function  mittai:parse-thru($n as node())
{
   for $z in $n/node() 
     return mittai:dispatch($z)
};

declare function mittai:dispatch($n as node())
{
   typeswitch($n)
      case text() return $n
      case element(p) return element{ fn:node-name($n) } {mittai:parse-thru($n)} 
      case element(span) return element{ fn:node-name($n) } {mittai:parse-thru($n)}       
      case element(body) return element{ fn:node-name($n) } {mittai:parse-thru($n)}       
      default return element{ fn:node-name($n) } {$n/@*, mittai:parse-thru($n)} 

};

let $d := doc('myfile.html')
return <html> {mittai:parse-thru($d)} </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out.  I agree that my approach is definitely a non-functional approach.  I don't have a lot of experience in the functional paradigm.  Primarily imperative.

Comment: @Alejandro -- can you please provide us some pointers for the identify transformation which u feel perfect.

Comment: It's not a matter of perfection, just convention. Check `local:copy` function on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This XQuery (using the common identity function):

```
declare variable $Prop as element()* :=
       (<prop name="em">font-style:italic</prop>,
        <prop name="strong">font-weight:600</prop>,
        <prop name="u">text-decoration:underline</prop>);

declare function local:copy($element as element()) {
  element {node-name($element)}
    {$element/@*,
     for $child in $element/node()
        return if ($child instance of element())
          then local:match($child)
          else $child
    }
};
declare function local:match($element as element()) {
  if ($element/self::span[@style])
  then local:replace($element)
  else local:copy($element)
};
declare function local:replace($element as element()) {
  let $prop := local:parse($element/@style)
  let $no-match := $prop[not(.=$Prop)]
  return element {node-name($element)}
           {$element/@* except $element/@style,
            if (exists($no-match))
            then attribute style
                   {string-join($no-match,';')}
            else (),
            local:nested($Prop[.=$prop]/@name,$element)}
};
declare function local:parse($string as xs:string) {
  for $property in tokenize($string,';')[.]
  return
    <prop>{
      replace(normalize-space($property),'( )?:( )?',':')
   }</prop>
};
declare function local:nested($names as xs:string*,
                              $element as element()) {
  if (exists($names))
  then element {$names[1]}
         {local:nested($names[position()>1],$element)}
  else for $child in $element/node()
       return if ($child instance of element())
          then local:match($child)
          else $child
};
local:match(*)
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <head>   </head>
    <body style=" font-family:'Lucida Grande'; font-size:14pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text</p>
        <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"/>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text 
            <span>
                <strong>bold text</strong>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-weight:600;"/>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text 
            <span>
                <em>italics text</em>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-style:italic;"/>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text 
            <span>
                <u>underline text</u>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"/>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text 
            <span>
                <strong>
                    <u>bold underline text</u>
                </strong>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">plain text 
            <span>
                <strong>bold text </strong>
            </span>
            <span>
                <strong>
                    <u>bold underline text</u>
                </strong>
            </span>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```